# crontab script not working

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, cron

Below is my job.sh File

```
echo 'Job Started Running'
echo 'password' | sudo  ./logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/bin/contact-index-logstash.conf
echo 'Job Ended'
```

Below is my `sudo crontab -e`

```
* * * * *  bash ~/job.sh > ~/log.log 2>&1
```

below is my cron status

```
>  service cron status ● cron.service - Regular background program

> processing daemon    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service;

> enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: active (running) since Thu
> 2017-11-09 22:09:03 IST; 1h 40min ago

>      Docs: man:cron(8)  Main PID: 869 (cron)

>     Tasks: 1    Memory: 12.3M

>       CPU: 1min 40.378s    CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
>            └─869 /usr/sbin/cron -f

> 
> Nov 09 23:42:01 akshay CRON[6264]: pam_unix(cron:session): session
>opened for user root by (uid=0) Nov 09 23:43:01 akshay CRON[6270]:
> pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 

>Nov 09 23:43:01 akshay CRON[6271]: (root) CMD (bash ~/job.sh > ~/log.log
> 2>&1) 

Nov 09 23:43:01 akshay CRON[6270]: pam_unix(cron:session):
> session closed for user root Nov 09 23:44:01 akshay CRON[6293]:
> pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 
Nov 09
> 23:44:01 akshay CRON[6294]: (root) CMD (bash ~/job.sh > ~/log.log
> 2>&1)
```

When I execute the sh file directly on shell , it runs without any error but under crontab it is not working..

Comment: Since the job is run by `root`, `~/job.sh` will be `/root/job.sh` and `~/log.log` will be `/root/log.log` . Also `sudo` will be unnecessary (and piping your password to sudo **doubly** unnecessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestions in [@steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974792/crontab-script-not-working#comment1563324_974792) here's how it should be.

Your `job.sh` file (assuming `logstash` is located in the same location!):

```
echo 'Job Started Running'
./logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/bin/contact-index-logstash.conf
echo 'Job Ended'
```

Your root's `crontab`:

```
* * * * *  /home/username/job.sh > /home/username/log.log 2>&1
```

`cron` runs your script with `sh` by default, so I removed the unnecessary `bash` subshell – if you nevertheless need it just add it again.

Comment: @Akshay Deep Lamba: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Actually it's [**the** way](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites. ;)